# AMD GPUs Dynamic Parallelism

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu, amd-processor

Does AMD GPUs support dynamic parallelism ? If so kindly let me know the GPU model details and  I know OpenCL 2.0 supports Dynamic parallelism. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AMD's press releases say that the FirePro [S9150](http://www.amd.com/en-us/press-releases/Pages/worlds-most-powerful-2014aug06.aspx) and FirePro [W9100](http://www.amd.com/en-us/press-releases/Pages/amd-flagship-professional-2014apr7.aspx) cards will support OpenCL 2.0 (including SVM and dynamic parallelism) "later this year".

Answer (score -1):

For dynamic parallelism to work, you will most likely need a GCN architecture model (HD7000 and beyond), but the safest choice is models based on the Hawaii chip, or a Kaveri APU. These two will 100% take care of dynamic parallelism.